# Not sure why my while loop is throwing error

Tags: bash

I have the following code for connecting to a server. But I seem to get an error on the while loop portion. Without the second condition in the while loop it works fine, but i need to second condition as well.

Any thoughts?

The error is:

```
./test.sh: line 83: conditional binary operator expected
./test.sh: line 83: syntax error near `LINE'
./test.sh: line 83: `while [[ read LINE <&3;  &&  $((END-START)) -le 59 ]]'
```

The code is:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${SERVER}/${PORT}
echo "login $NICK $PASS" >&3

START=$(date +%s);
minutes=0
END=0

while [[ read LINE <&3;  &&  $((END-START)) -le 59 ]]
do

END=$(date +%s);
secs=$((END-START))
if [[ "$secs" == 60 ]]
then
minutes=$((minutes + 1))
START=$(date +%s);
echo "$minutes have passed since I connected." >&3
fi
done
```

Comment: `[[` is not syntax for grouping; it's a command in its own right and as such, does not just wrap another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
while read LINE <&3 && [[ $((END-START)) -le 59 ]]
```

You can also use the arithmetic conditional

```
while read LINE <&3 && ((END - START <= 59))
```

Comment: This has fixed the issue at hand. Thanks for the awesome response time.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line <&3 && (( (END-START) < 59 ))
```

may be neater I guess

---

<sup>**note:** Use lower-case varaibles for your script coz upper case variables are usually reserved for system ie `LINE->line`. Similarly with `END`, `START` and so on.`</sup>